# Securely load a HTML resource into MFC dialog

Tags: mfc

There is a HTML resource defined

```
IDR_HTML_HTMLDISPLAYDIALOG HTML                    "res\\HTMLDisplayDialog.htm"
```

This HTML resource is loaded into a CDHtmlDialog. 
As a part of tightening the security to our products, the base product uses **LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE** flag.

Because of this change, the resource is not loaded and the dialog hangs/crashes. Is there a way to securely get the URL to the resource in some other manner?

Comment: *"As a part of tightening the security to our products, the base product uses LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag."* - Unclear, how that could be part of a security scheme. In all, as asked, the question is too fuzzy to be answerable.

Comment: Ok. It is done by another team in another country. All I know is that, that particular flag is used. And I somehow need to obtain the html resource anyway. I will update the question once I get more details.

Comment: @nam How exactly this html is loaded now?, I never used this LOAD_LIRARY_... flag,but here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141120-00/?p=43573, you can find that it should allow for manual loading with Find­Resource, Load­Resource, and Enum­Resource­Types.